# Bring up of console of Apache Spark Service in Bluemix hangs

Tags: service, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I create an instance of the Apache Service but when when I try to bring up it's console the console page hangs indefinitely with a spinning cursor.

Comment: Could you give details on the OS and the browser you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this stage of the Bluemix Apache Spark beta, you can only create apps from the Spark Starter boilerplate at the top of the catalog. A Spark Starter app will automatically create an instance of the Apache Spark service and will give you access to that service instance strictly for the purpose of using Jupyter/IPython notebooks. Later on in the beta, you should expect more functionality to be made available; and direct usage of a spark service instance is quite possible ;-)

Once you create an app from the Spark Starter boilerplate, you can click on the route/URL from the dashboard for the app and that will take you into a home page for that app. The Launch button you see there will take you to the Jupyter/IPython notebook server that utilizes the Apache Spark bluemix service.